# What does the g mean after the isotope given?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, notation, stability, isotopes

I'm familiar with notation such as Sc-44m standing for the meta stable state of Sc-44.

What does Sc-44g mean? There are a few examples of this notation; here's one:

http://iopscience.iop.org/0031-9155/60/17/6847/pdf/0031-9155_60_17_6847.pdf

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is already on page 2 of your link above:

"Among the large number of radionuclides of medical interest, Sc-44 is
promising for PET imaging. Either the **ground-state Sc-44g** or the metastable-state Sc-44m can be used for such applications, depending on the moleculeused as vector."

So the metastable state Sc-44m decays to the ground state Sc-44g.